# Theme Change per subdomain on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, wordpress-theming

does anyone know if its possible to change themes based on sub domains? I've tried WP Subdomains and Virtual Themes plugins, neither one works with current version of wordpress. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use a fully different theme for each sub directory the best way is to use the Network feature (or multisite). You can have a main theme then run child themes for each subdomain site.

If the subdomain differences are minor cosmetic ones you should do them as separate CSS theme files that load based on the current subdomain.